# Limit the Size of Publisher Logs File

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1-hr1, logging

We have Publisher Logging enabled, which can be set in the Tridion MMC. This was working as expected from a long time creating the logs at the location "{%TridionDir%}/log".

**Issue:**

We noticed that file size of publisher logs was around 64 GB, needless to say we didn't want that big of a log file and tried to look for the option if we can set some file size limit on it, but couldn't find any setting to control it.

**What we tried:**

We know that most of the Tridion log files could be control for size (Rolling Policies) in "Logback.xml" file as answered [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/t%20questions/3815/limit-the-size-of-each-log-file-and-set-max-history). But looks like Publisher Logs can't be controlled from it(Correct me If I am wrong).

We observed that Tridion uses Microsoft's Enterprise Library Logging Application Block for publisher logging and the listener is set in the file "TcmPublisher.exe.config" as below:

```
<add fileName="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log\TcmPublisher.log"
        formatter="Log Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"
        traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"
        name="Tridion CM Publisher Log File" />
```

So the Listener Type used is `FlatFileTraceListener`, which has no file size limit or rolling policy support. I tried using `RollingFileTraceListener` in place of `FlatFileTraceListener` as it support rolling policy but it didn't work and stopped logging. Also looks like there is some xsd to validate TcmPublisher.exe.config file as it throws a validation error in MMC as below:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is there a setting to limit the file size of the Publisher Logs?
2. If not, is there some other advanced way achieving it?

Answer (score 4):

I note that the logging defaults to *false* and I wonder if this is the reason. I don't see anywhere that you can control the size of the log (or to have a larger set of data broken across multiple files) as you would in say, Log4Net.

I think the answer is "manage this by the process in DevOps" ... if you *must* log[1] then someone should be monitoring[2] the filesize and/or have a {automated?} process for renaming (or removing) the current file and letting the Publisher create a new one[3].

[1] Probably only WARN, if not ERROR

[2] Monitoring can be as simple as a PowerShell monitoring app

[3] It may be that you need to stop the Publisher Service and therefore do this out of hours

Comment: It is indeed not possible to configure a rolling log file for publisher file logging (yet); publisher file logging is normally only used temporarily for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Hi @saurabh , did you get any solution for this ?