# Possible reasons for "SDL Web Content manager Pubisher" service is not running

Tags: web8, publishing

We are using SDL web 8.5 with Legacy Architecture (File system) , no microservices , old publishing architecture (httpupload) . Publisher and Tridion is on same server.
From last few days we observed that our "SDL Web Content manager Pubisher" stopped 4-5 times, then each time i had to restart this manually. I tried to open the log file (TcmPublisher.log) but could not because the file size is 2GB (no way to add rolling as [Limit the Size of Publisher Logs File](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/limit-the-size-of-publisher-logs-file)) . is there a way to debug this failures ? or what can be the possible reasons for this?

We have SDL Monitoring Service installed and in running state, i see Publisher configured in heart beat monitoring in cd_moniotr.config file. logging for monitoring service is also in place in cd_monitor config file but i do not see any logs generated there.(might be state change of the service is an "Info", and we are writing only "Errors")

I can see there are recovery options in this windows service properties, but still it does not restart the service.

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail. What is content manager version? Are you using topology manager or legacy publishing? Is this a scaled out solution?
Publisher service will stop if topology is unreachable.

Comment: Was there CPU SPIKE in those few days. ? do you have any error logged in the event viewer.

Comment: I will check cpu spike tomorrow, but nothing is logged in event viewer. Thanks

Comment: The errors should also be available in the Tridion Event Log. Perhaps you could take a look there and update your question with any details you find?

Comment: Could be publisher logs enabled DEBUG logger mode that could be the reason log file 2GB? Go to SDL Console to double-check publisher debug is enabled true or false?